# Selects en html con angular y javascript

Tags: html, typescript, formularios

Hola estoy intentando recibir los valores de un campo para editar en un formulario de edicion, pero a la hora de mostrar los valores por defecto en los selects sucede que el primero no recoge el valor, sin embargo el segundo si. Que podria estar pasando? Les dejo el código del html de los dos selects:

```
<div class="mb-3">
 <label for="tipo de campo" class="form-label">Tipo de campo</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]=" tipoCampoSeleccionado " class="form-select">
       <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione una opcion</option>
       <option *ngFor="let listaCamEdit of listaTipoCampos" 
          [value]="listaCamEdit.id">
           {{ listaCamEdit.descripcion }}
       </option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="mb-3">
   <label for="tipo de visualizacion" class="form-label">Tipo de visualizacion</label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="tipoVisualizacionCampoEditar" class="form-select">
         <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione una opcion</option>
         <option *ngFor="let listaVisEdit of listaTipoVisualizacion" 
          [value]="listaVisEdit.id">
          {{ listaVisEdit.descripcion }}
        </option>
     </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Lo hemos solucionado añadiendo un "name" en el "select".

Comment: agrega el codigo del component.ts